# In chrome with a greasemonkey extension, how can I modify an `<a...>` construct to strip out the onclick= attribute?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey

I want to modify an internal webpage to strip away some of the `onclick` behavior of certain links.

The internal webpage has a bunch of links like:

```
<a href="/slm/detail/ar/3116370" onclick="rallyPorthole.showDetail('/ar/view.sp','3116370','pj/b');return false;">foo de fa fa</a>
```

How can I do an extension to Chrome so it does the following:

```
for link in all_links:
    if link's href attribute matches '/slm/detail/ar/...':
        remove the onclick attribute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding [this script](http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:0GOPB3SwhHkJ:userscripts.org/scripts/show/9184+remove+onclick+greasemonkey&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), the following code can be put in a file ending in `.user.js` and installed in Firefox or Chrome.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Rally Onclick Nuke
// @namespace     http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/download/
// @description   Nukes the "onclick" attribute from user story links so you can CTRL click a link and have it open in a new tab
// @include       https://*rally.sp
// ==/UserScript==

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var node = links[i];
    var link = node.getAttribute("href");
    if (link && link.indexOf("slm/detail/ar/") > -1 ) {
        if (node.getAttribute("onclick")) {
          node.removeAttribute("onclick");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `document.getElementByTagName("a")` you can also use `document.links` which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.links).

So to modify Ross Rogers' code:

```
var node, links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; node = links[i]; i++) {
  if (node.indexOf("slm/detail/ar/") > -1 ) {
      if (node.getAttribute("onclick")) {
        node.removeAttribute("onclick");
      }
  }
}
```